# Using manifest.json to return a file path in php

Tags: php, json, gulp

First off, please excuse my methodology, I'm sure there are much better ways to do this but I'm self taught and definitely not a pro :D

Anyway, I'm learning how to revision assets using [`gulp-rev-rewrite`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev-rewrite) and I've gotten most of the way there.

My gulp tasks are all working, revisioning is fine and I can generate a `rev-manifest.json` file which contains revisioned filenames, e.g:

```
"app.css": "app-df7223f44c.css"
```

I now can't work out how to use the data in the manifest.json file to specify a file path in my php. I found [another resource](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/blob/master/integration.md) from a similar gulp package which contained a .php function I hoped to adapt:

```
<?php /**
 * @param  string  $filename
 * @return string
 */
function asset_path($filename) {
    $manifest_path = '../dist/rev-manifest.json';

    if (file_exists($manifest_path)) {
        $manifest = json_decode(file_get_contents($manifest_path), TRUE);
    } else {
        $manifest = [];
    }

    if (array_key_exists($filename, $manifest)) {
        return $manifest[$filename];
    }

    return $filename;
}
?>
```

I insert this function using

```
 <?php require 'require/filepaths.php';?>
```

And then try to use the file path like so:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php asset_path('dist/app.css');?>" rel="preload">
```

Only it's not working and I'm stumped.

The file path that returns is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="" rel="preload">
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I tried manually including the a filepath in `filepaths.php` which worked, so I assume the problem is in that file somewhere?

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your JSON entry is actually `app.css` then this function will fail to find a match because you're looking for `dist/app.css`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting! :D JSON tracks revisions to app.css made with gulp e.g. `"app.css": "app-df7223f44c.css"`, so I'm trying to link to `"dist/app-df7223f44c.css"` and `dist/app.css` is set `asset_path`'s default value as a fallback

Comment: Add your actual JSON manifest.

Comment: Hi Allen - the entire file is 

`{
  "app.css": "app-df7223f44c.css"
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Allen - think I have it now.

You were right in that the url wasn't correct relative to the site root. I found [the answer here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev/issues/200#issuecomment-353687226).

Basically I needed to pass `dist/` into the filepath in the manifest, so the key was an edit to the GULP recipe from:

```
gulp.task('revision', function() {
  return gulp.src(['dist/app.css', 'dist/app.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({
      merge: true
    }))
    .pipe(revDel({ dest: 'dist' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Rev task complete' }));
});
```

to:

```
gulp.task('revision', function() {
  return gulp.src(['dist/app.css', 'dist/app.js'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(rev())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'))
    .pipe(rename({
        dirname: "dist/" // rename dir in manifest
    }))
    .pipe(rev.manifest({
      merge: true
    }))
    .pipe(revDel({ dest: 'dist' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Rev task complete' }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you posted your manifest, I'm not sure how you're expecting this to work. If you `var_dump` the manifest after you `json_decode` it, you're going to see that the array key is `app.css` not the `dist/app.css` you're looking for.

`<?php asset_path('app.css');?>` should work just fine.

Comment: Oh so the array key is relative to the `manifest.json` file, not `head.php`, which is where `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php asset_path('dist/app.css');?>" rel="preload">` lives? 

If so, I did not realise that. I'm not sure how I was expecting it to work either  I don't know what I'm doing 

Comment: Ah.  `<?php asset_path('app.css');?>` is a 404 :(

Comment: We're getting out of the scope of this particular question. That means whatever generated your manifest, or the URL you're generating is not correct relative to your doc root.